# Mysql Month - Year Comparison

Tags: mysql

How can I make a query that conditions a Month - Year only selection? Like, Where the range is January 2013 - December 2014?

I have a "date" column in my table.

I usually do a date range like `WHERE date >= ? AND date <= ?` which is from date to date. I only want to select the Month and Year only, without the day.

Now I want to do `WHERE date >= (January 2013) AND date date <= (December 2014)`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you use 01 January 2013 and 01 December 2014 as a filter . it will give you same result that you want.

Comment: Because the company want it that way. I used it for report generation which they said can filter only month -year to month -year not from date to date to avoid putting a day on it.

Comment: But when you apply any function on column then it will not use indexing so your query will be slower in that case .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m") BETWEEN '2013-01' AND '2014-12';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT fields
FROM table
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date) BETWEEN '2013-01' AND '2014-12'
```

You also could use DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m') instead of EXTRACT.

Answer (score 1):

use Month and Year function of mysql [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a select like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM supportContacts
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y') BETWEEN '2013' AND '2014'
AND DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m') BETWEEN '01' AND '12';
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49615/13)

Comment: 02-2000 will fall into that range.   Perhaps if you changed the order to "%Y-%m" instead...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MySampleTable
WHERE Month(create_dt) IN (1, 2, 3)
AND Year(create_dt) = 2013
```

If you've got a lot of data in your table, and the date field you're interested in is indexed, you might want to bound this with a between start date and end date.   Evaluation of these functions will force a table scan (since the date value has to be massaged by the two functions in order to be interpreted correctly), so this will run slow.   Anything you can do to reduce the number of rows being evaluated will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date_format(`date`,'%M %Y') >= 'January 2013' AND date_format(`date`,'%M %Y') <= 'December 2014'
```