# How to compare date(year, month) with date(day, month, year)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql command which I want to check if the date(year, month) is in between the date(day, month, year) and date(day, month, year). Following is my SQL command:

```
SELECT *
FROM paytran
WHERE
    (StaffID BETWEEN '01' AND '01')
    AND STR_TO_DATE('01/04/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(DateFrom, '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(DateTo, '%d/%m/%Y')
    AND SubGroup = '1'
    AND Week1 = '1'
    AND PaymentMonth = STR_TO_DATE('2016/04', '%Y%m') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/03/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('31/12/2016', '%d/%m/%Y')
    AND FO = 'F'
```

MySQL gives no error but the result should not be empty.

Comment: Are you sure `SubGroup = '`'` is not a typo?

Comment: Yes, it is a typo.. Haha thanks for edit. I already change the SubGroup value

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m") BETWEEN '2013-01' AND '2014-12';
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541196/3155780

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, this version seems simpler:

```
SELECT *
FROM paytran
WHERE StaffID LIKE '01%' AND
      '2016-04-01' BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo AND
       SubGroup = '1' AND
       Week1 = '1' AND
       DATE_FORMAT(PaymentMonth, '%Y%m') BETWEEN '201604' and '201612' AND
       FO = 'F';
```

In general, you don't need to convert dates to strings for comparisons.  If a date is expected, then a string in the format of YYYY-MM-DD will be converted automatically.

Comment: But 201604 and 201612 is actually based on database column and the 201604 is actually 01/03/2016 and 201612 is actually 31/12/2016. The command also still not working. Hehe

Comment: @JohnsYong . . . They are not in your question.  Of course, you can still use `date_format()` if you like on the database column.

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot for your help. I am very appreciate it